# Arangodb: How to use MERGE_RECURSIVE() With an Array

Tags: arangodb, aql

In AQL, the `MERGE_RECURSIVE` function cannot take an array as an input. How then would I use said function with the result of a previous query, which is, of course, an array?

For example, if the output of my query result is:

```
[
  {
    "John": {"city": "Berlin"}
  },
  {
    "John": {"country": "Germany"}
  }
]
```

I want to `MERGE_RECURSIVE(myResult)` to return:

```
{
  "John": {"city": "Berlin", "country": "Germany"}
}
```

**I just need a way to use MERGE_RECURSIVE with my query's output array**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you got an array like `x = [1, 2, 3]` but the function you want to pass this to requires each element as separate argument, so `SOME_FUNC(1, 2, 3)` instead of `SOME_FUNC( [1, 2, 3] )`, then there's the [APPLY() function](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.4/AQL/Functions/Miscellaneous.html#apply) to spread the array:

`APPLY("SOME_FUNC", [1, 2, 3] )`

This is essentially like the following call:

`SOME_FUNC(x[0], x[1], x[2])`

... but you spare yourself to type all that with `APPLY()` and it will work with a variable number of elements in the array. So the solution in your case is:

```
RETURN APPLY("MERGE_RECURSIVE", myResult)
```